# Prove that $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x≥0$ when $f(0)=1$ and $f′(x) \leq 0$ for all $x>0$ such that $f(x)>1$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, and assume that:

- $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$
- $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$
- $f'(x) \leq 0$ for all $x > 0$ such that $f(x) > 1$
- $f(0) = 1$

Prove that $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \geq0$.

I'm trying to argue this with an elegant as argument as possible. I would think to do something like suppose there exists some $c \in (0,\infty)$ such that $f(c)>1$ and try to reach some sort of contradiction with the fact that $f'(c) \leq 0$ there.

Since the function starts with the value 1 at 0, I assume there is some $c$ such that $f(c) >1$ with the special property that its the largest value so far $(f(c) > f(x) \text{ where } x \in (0,c))$

Since $f$ is continuous and its the largest value so far up to $c$ there is a neighborhood around $c$ such that there is a point in the neighborhood $p < c$ such that $1 < f(p) < f(c)$ and the derivative $f'(p) > 0$, which is a contradiction.

Any feedback on my argument?

Comment: Your approach has a basic flaw. No such largest $c$ can be guaranteed. Such things are possible only when we are dealing with closed intervals and not for intervals of type $[0,\infty)$. The right approach is to consider just a $c>0$ with $f(c) >1$. Now let $b\in[0,c]$ be largest such value of $x$ for which $f(x) =1$.  Now analyse $f$ in $[b, c] $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is right, just that one can't assure the existence of  a maximum on a non-compact set, so $c$ need not exist.

However, if we consider just one such $c$, we can  get a contradiction.

To do  this, let $c$ be a value such that $f(c) > 1$, and let $b$ be the largest value of $x$ in $[0,c]$ such that $f(x) = 1$, as the hint above says. Such a $b$ exists because $f(0) = 1$, so  the level set of $1$ is non-empty. Note that $c > b$.

On $[b,c]$, it is clear that by the mean value theorem, $f(c) - f(b) = (c-b) f'(d)$ for some $d \in (b,c)$. This implies,  that since the LHS is positive and $c>b$, hence $f'(d) > 0$, but then $f(d) > 1$, since $d > b$ and $d \in [c,b]$. This contradicts the statement made in the question, hence no such $c$ exists.

Hence, the result follows.

Comment: Great Answer - thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted my hint to be completed. +1

Comment: Thank you, @ParamanandSingh